# How to simplify the following vector cross products?

Tags: vector-analysis

Let the position vector be $\mathbf{x}$, normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, rotation angular vector $\mathcal{\alpha}$ and rotation matrix $\mathcal{M}$ which contains 2nd order of vector $\mathcal{\alpha}$.
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x}+\mathcal{M}\tag{1}\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf{n}}=\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{\alpha}\times\mathbf{n}+\mathcal{M}\tag{2}\mathbf{n}
\end{align}
The cross product of (1) and (2) then takes a form
\begin{align}\label{eq:xXn_expand}
\hat{\mathbf{x}}\times\hat{\mathbf{n}}=&\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{x}\times(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{n})+(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\times\mathbf{n}+(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\times(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{n})+\\&(\mathcal{M}\mathbf{x})\times\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{x}\times(\mathcal{M}\mathbf{n})+(higherorder)
\end{align}
The 2nd and 3rd terms can be combined
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}\times(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{n})+(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\times\mathbf{n}&=\mathcal{\alpha}\times(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n})\\
\end{align}
and the 4th term expands
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\times(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{n})&=[(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{n}]\mathcal{\alpha}+\mathbf{n}
[(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathcal{\alpha}]=[(\mathcal{\alpha}\times\mathbf{x})\cdot\mathbf{n}]\mathcal{\alpha}
\end{align}
However the matrix vector terms are left mysterious to me. I tried
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{M}\mathbf{x})\times\mathbf{n}+\mathbf{x}\times(\mathcal{M}\mathbf{n})&=\varepsilon_{ijk}(M_{jl}x_ln_k+x_jM_{kl}n_l)\\
&=
\end{align}
By brutal expansion,
\begin{align}
-\mathcal{M}_{11}x_1n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{11}x_3n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{11}x_1n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{11}x_2n_1
-\mathcal{M}_{12}x_2n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{12}x_3n_2
+\mathcal{M}_{12}x_2n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{12}x_2n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{13}x_3n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{13}x_3n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{13}x_3n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{13}x_2n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{21}x_1n_3
-\mathcal{M}_{21}x_3n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{21}x_1n_1
-\mathcal{M}_{21}x_1n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{22}x_2n_3
-\mathcal{M}_{22}x_3n_2
+\mathcal{M}_{22}x_1n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{22}x_2n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{23}x_3n_3
-\mathcal{M}_{23}x_3n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{23}x_1n_3
-\mathcal{M}_{23}x_3n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{31}x_2n_1
-\mathcal{M}_{31}x_1n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{31}x_1n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{31}x_1n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{32}x_2n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{32}x_2n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{32}x_1n_2
+\mathcal{M}_{32}x_2n_1
+\mathcal{M}_{33}x_2n_3
-\mathcal{M}_{33}x_3n_2
-\mathcal{M}_{33}x_1n_3
+\mathcal{M}_{33}x_3n_1
\end{align}
The next simplification to be in terms of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{n})$?